# Error processing intent from file: 'intents/<intent-name>_usersays_<lang>.json'. Uploaded file contains invalid Intent

Tags: import, zip, dialogflow-es

I am working on a library which is creating the dialogflow configuration. When I try to upload the generated zip file I get for each "*usersays*" file is causing an error: *`Error processing intent from file: 'intents/<intent-name>_usersays_<lang>.json'. Uploaded file contains invalid Intent.`*

It seems that I have some kind of syntax error, but I'm unable to find it.

I created an empty Intent called "Aaa" for testing and exported it. Here are the file contents of the files.

`Aaa_usersays_de.json`:

```
[
  {
    "id": "f8f65eae-2605-4660-aca0-fc738a3364b7",
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "aaa",
        "userDefined": false
      }
    ],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

Here is my generated file (`SOME.fancy.name_usersays_de.json`):

```
[
  {
    "id": "c1ceef44-355f-38e6-a96a-e24ac5a556ba",
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "<utterance 1>?",
        "userDefined": false
      }
    ],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "5d6b53d7-75c0-324c-9fb5-474a931c937a",
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "<utterance 2>?",
        "userDefined": false
      }
    ],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "452025c2-b66d-3486-b1b7-c83849a00e54",
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "<utterance 3>?",
        "userDefined": false
      }
    ],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0
  },
  {
    "id": "e73afbbb-7a12-3f20-a375-4dcceedb47a8",
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "<utterance 4>",
        "userDefined": false
      }
    ],
    "isTemplate": false,
    "count": 0
  }
]
```

The utterances just use Latin letters no utf-8 issues possible. I use the same value of the Action and Intent Name.

Someone any idea?

Comment: Unfunny fun fact when I enter the utterances by hand and export them then I get the same structure just with other UUIDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a response from Google. My zip file was missing the `package.json`, this high complex file needs to contain this JSON:

```
{"version": "1.0.0"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the zip format is documented anywhere, but to create an intent you would have to send [this object](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#Intent), which has the training phrases split into individual parts. The zip export format seems to differ slightly from the official API spec, I don't think you can use it to reliably interact with a Dialogflow agent.